# RxNetty download large file

Tags: spring, rx-netty

I'm trying to create controller that download large file using `RxNetty`

I write something stupid like

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "largeFile")
public DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<byte[]>> largeFile() throws IOException {
    Observable<ResponseEntity<byte[]>> observable = RxNetty.createHttpGet(URL)
                                            .flatMap(AbstractHttpContentHolder::getContent)
                                            .map(data -> {
                                                byte[] bytes = new byte[data.readableBytes()];
                                                data.readBytes(bytes);
                                                return new ResponseEntity<>(bytes, HttpStatus.OK);
                                            });
    DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<byte[]>> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<>();
    observable.subscribe(deferredResult::setResult, deferredResult::setErrorResult);
    return deferredResult;
}
```

Nevertheless I have the following error:

```
Caused by: io.netty.handler.codec.TooLongFrameException: HTTP content length exceeded 1048576 bytes.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default client in RxNetty 0.4.x aggregates HTTP payload which has a limit on the maximum content length. The exception you see is because of that limit. You can alter the default client using a PipelineConfigurator as shown in this example:

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxNetty/blob/0.4.x/rxnetty-examples/src/main/java/io/reactivex/netty/examples/http/chunk/HttpChunkClient.java#L49

after which the payload will be chunked into multiple buffers.

Alternatively, if you know the max size, then you can use an appropriate payload aggregator in the configurator.